# Responsive datatable with first column as checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable that has first column as checkbox for row selection.

```
columnDefs: [{
  orderable: false,
  className: 'select-checkbox',
  targets: 0
}]
```

Trying to make the datatable as responsive, but when I tried, the checkbox in the first column is replaced with expandable icon. Can someone tell me how can I retain both the icons(checkbox and expansion) in the same column.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "bPaginate": false,
  "serverSide" : true,
  "searching": true,
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  responsive: {
          details: {
            type: 'column',
            target: 0
          }
        },

  "ajax" : {

   url : location.origin+"/hello/rest" + "/login/getList",
   "type" : "POST",

   "error" : function(xhr, error, thrown) {
    handleServerErrorResponseForAdmin(thrown);
   }
  },
//  <th></th>

Comment: "columns" : [{
   "data" : "empty"
  }, {
   "data" : "empty"
  }, {
   "data" : "paymentid"
  }, {
   "data" : "uploadDate"
  }, {
   "data" : "emailsubject"
  }, {
   "data" : "closingDate"
  }, {
   "data" : "pstatus"
  }
  ],
  initComplete: function() {
     },
     columnDefs: [ 
                   {

Comment: orderable: false,
         targets: 0,
         className: 'control',
       },{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   1
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        select: true
        ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are attempting to use the same column for two different thing - **responsive control** and **select checkbox**. That isn't going to work since the click event will trigger both.

You can add an extra `<td>` element to each row in your table so it targets that instead of the column with the actual content in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: '.select-checkbox',
      items: 'row',
    },
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column',
        target: 0
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 0,
        className: 'control'
      },
      {
        targets: 1,
        className: 'select-checkbox'
      },
      {
        targets: [0, 1],
        orderable: false
      }
    ],
    order: [2, 'asc']
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.1.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$3,120</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$5,300</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$4,800</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks Prashant. It worked. Really appreciate the quick help. I am seeing that the first column icon is getting cut (expansion control icon). Can you tell me how i can make it right aligned.

Comment: You can easily make right aligned by using checkbox td at the end

Comment: May I follow up on this? It seem don't work when using DataTables Editor.

Comment: @LekzFlores, did you try it out with the editor. If so, what are the errors you've gotten? You can send fiddle link of http://live.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to use the first column (checkbox) as a row selector but the responsive mode is causing you problems since both the checkbox and the "+" button (responsive) are pressed, then what you can do is send a first blank column. Simply add one more  to your  and one  (blank) to your  .